# What is the correct usage of "In light of"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, idioms

I'm considering two different forms of a sentence:

> In light of these limitations as described…
>
> In the light of these limitations as described…

Which usage is correct?

Comment: I noticed some dictionaries list the idiom as _in (the) light of_, but I can only remember hearing the shorter version (i.e., _in light of_). Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: I think in US it is "in light of"

Comment: That means there is no meaning and grammatical difference?

Comment: I think it means "in the light of" would sound oddly wordy in the US, and "in light of" might sound oddly terse in some parts of the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US,  “in light of” sounds natural and is well understood, while “in the light of” (if intended to mean  “in consideration of” or  “taking into account” rather than “illuminated by”) sounds awkward.

Snailboat's comment, that  “BNC gives 1798 for *in the light of* and 125 for *in light of*. COCA gives 4678 for *in light of* and 1474 for *in the light of*”, suggests the opposite is true in the UK.

COCA = [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and BNC = British National Corpus ([1](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/),[2](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/)).

Comment: I have a very minor point to make: I used `code` rather than *italics* because I consider search terms to be **data**, distinct in form from mentioned text.  This can be seen in examples like `everyone 's`, where the search term contains a space that the corresponding mentioned text would not, or in `un american`, which may correspond to mentioned text like *un-American* with a hyphen and capitalization, or in queries containing operators such as `colour / (color + colour)`, which don't correspond directly to any mentioned text.

Comment: (But the italics are okay here, because the queries happen to correspond to mentioned text in this example.)

Comment: @snailboat, thanks for pointing out the rationale for `code` formatting.  I noticed it but didn't think of a reason to use it